# Materialized Views not showing in Looker?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-11, looker

After connecting my PostgreSQL 11.11 to Looker, I am unable to see the marginalized views created in my database. Is there a reason they aren't showing there?

Comment: under different schema? or permission issue?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem and contacted the Looker support team. This is currently not enabled for some reason. AFAIK they were working with their engineering team to enable it as of Mai 2021.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try viewing the state of all mv's via,

`select * from stv_mv_info;` ?

Comment: This reads more like a comment than an answer to me: One of the primary purposes of the question's comment section is to ask for clarification or more details from the asker.